# haxis text doesn't show all records and can't be slanted

Tags: google-visualization

I use Google Charts to show a stacked bar chart (two bars per year).

The data displays just fine but the haxis (years) should be slanted (i.e. 30 degrees) and should display more than every fifth year.

Any suggestion is more than welcome. Thanks!

Picture is in my dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/niru4cyw8x4m98m/stack.png?dl=0

```
"data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,<html>  <head>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['', 'Investiertes Vermögen', 'Kumulierter Gewinn/Verlust'],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr01a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital01a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg01a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr01b & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital01b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg01b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr02a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital02a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg02a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr02a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital02b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg02b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr03a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital03a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg03a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr03a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital03b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg03b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr04a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital04a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg04a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr04a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital04b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg04b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr05a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital05a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg05a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr05a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital05b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg05b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr06a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital06a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg06a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr06a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital06b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg06b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr07a & ",  "& InvestKapital::InvestKapital07a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg07a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr07a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital07b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg07b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr08a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital08a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg08a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr08b & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital08b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg08b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr09a & ",  "& InvestKapital::InvestKapital09a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg09a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr09a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital09b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg09b & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr10a & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital10a & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg10a & "],
          [" & InvestKapital::Jahr10b & ", " & InvestKapital::InvestKapital10b & "," & InvestKapital::KumErfolg10b & "]

        ], false);
         var options = {
           isStacked: true,
           tooltip: {
                         textStyle: {color: '#000000', fontName: 'Mrs Eaves XL Serif OT', fontSize: 9},
               },
           legend: {position: 'none', textStyle: {color: '#000000', fontSize: 9}
               },
           vAxis: {minValue: 0,  
                       textStyle: {color: '#000000', fontName: 'Mrs Eaves XL Serif OT', fontSize: 10},
               },
           hAxis: {format: '', 
                       textStyle: {color: '#000000', fontName: 'Mrs Eaves XL Serif OT', fontSize: 9},
                       slantedText: true, 
                       maxAlternation: 1, // use a maximum of 1 line of labels
                       showTextEvery: 1, // show every label if possible
                       minTextSpacing: 1, // minimum spacing between adjacent labels, in pixels
              },
             series: {
              0:{color:'#0A5550'},
              1:{color:'#8C8C91'},
             },
        };    
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));}
    </script>  </head>  <body>
    <div id=\"columnchart_material\" style=\"width: 350px; height: 190px;\"></div>
  </body> </html>"
```

Comment: after the text "slantedTExt: true," I've added to my code "slantedTextAngle: 30" but still get the same result.

Comment: `google.charts.Bar` is considered a _material_ chart, there are several options that are not supported by _material_ charts, including `slantedText` and `slantedTextAngle`, see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143). instead, you could use a classic bar chart --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart`